# С помощью qsor отсортировать массив структур

Tags: сортировка, исключения, структуры, qsort

```
 struct litera {
    int num;
    float freq;
};

int comp2(const void * a, const void * b)
    {
        const litera *k = (const litera*)a;
        const litera *m = (const litera*)b;
        int s = ((m->freq) - (k->freq));
        return s;
    }

    void chast(void) {
        int mass[32];
        memset(mass, 0, sizeof(mass));
        for (int i = 0; i < 257; i++) {
            mass[txt[i]]++;
        }
        litera gold[32];
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            gold[i].num = i;
            gold[i].freq = mass[i];
        }
        qsort(gold, 32, sizeof(gold), comp2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            cout << gold[i].num << '\n';
        }
    }
```

Выдаёт исключение. Не могу разобраться в чём проблема, нужно отсортировать по freq. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

```
 qsort(gold, 32, sizeof(litera), comp2);
```